# Simple comparison promgram (for numbers) views letters as equals?

Tags: ruby

Probably just another noob question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere so...
I have to write a simple number comparison algorithm. I wrote the program so that if the numbers are not equal, the output will be a comparison, "the biggest number is x and the smallest is y"; if they are equal, the program will say so; and, just to be safe, else (if, for any reason, the numbers couldn't be compared) the output would be an error message.
Technically it should be a very simple task, but when I decided to test the possible outcomes, and what could cause the error, I found out that when the inputs are both letters, the output is that they are equal. When the first input is a number and the second a letter, there is no output, it ignores the rest of the code completely. If the first input is a letter and the second a number, the output is a comparison that says the letter is the smallest, being worth 0.

I'm just a beginner, so if anyone could explain to me why this happens or how could I tell the program to only compare a numerical input... Thanks in advance!

Here's the code (in Ruby):

```
puts "\nEnter two positive numbers:\n\nFirst:"
num1 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_f
puts "\nSecond:"
num2 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_f

if num1 != num2
    if num1 > num2
        biggest = num1
        smallest = num2
    elsif num1 < num2
        biggest = num2
        smallest = num1

    puts "\nThe biggest number is #{biggest} and the smallest is #{smallest}"

    end
elsif num1 == num2
    puts "\nThe numbers are equal."

else
    puts "\nError"
end
```

Comment: As a note: you have no output for this conditional `if num1 > num2`

Answer (score 2):

First, to explain the function's behavior:

> num1 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_f

These lines convert anything entered to a [float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html). When someone enters an integer, you don't notice because it just turns (for example) 1 into 1.0. Letters, though, return 0.0 when converted to floats. So the line quoted above turns any letter answer into 0.0.

This explains the comparison between numbers and letters, and indicates you tested with only positive numbers ;)

As @engineersmnky pointed out in the comments, you have no output when num1 > num2. Move your output outside of your inner if/elseif block.

**So what do you do about it?**

All of your input is going to be a string, so it gets tricky. One way would be to remove the `.to_f` and pass the input to `Integer()` inside a [begin/catch block](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html), catching the exception Integer throws if the input can't be converted to an integer properly:

```
puts "\nEnter two positive numbers:\n\nFirst:"
num1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
puts "\nSecond:"
num2 = $stdin.gets.chomp

begin
  num1 = Integer(num1)
  num2 = Integer(num2)
rescue ArgumentError
  { error handling code for improper input }
end

{ comparison code }
```

If the user enters a letter, `Integer()` will throw an ArgumentError, which this code will catch and you can handle it however you like (print the error message out, prompt the user to only enter integers, quit, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to point out the following...

```
if num1 != num2
  if num1 > num2
    biggest = num1
    smallest = num2
  elsif num1 < num2
    biggest = num2
    smallest = num1
    puts "\nThe biggest number is #{biggest} and the smallest is #{smallest}"
  end
```

Notice that the `puts` is ONLY in the block where num1 < num2, so it will never appear when num1 > num2

To fix this, just move the `end` line up

```
if num1 != num2
  if num1 > num2
    biggest = num1
    smallest = num2
  elsif num1 < num2
    biggest = num2
    smallest = num1
  end
  puts "\nThe biggest number is #{biggest} and the smallest is #{smallest}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When your inputs are letters then this happens:

```
"abc".to_f # => 0.0
```

So you are comparing

```
0.0 == 0.0
```

which obviously is true.

This is by definition of how `String#to_f` as well as `String#to_i` (would just return `0`) work.